# How to enable External Storage for Binary Data in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I would like to use the new External Binary Data for Core Data that came with iOS 5. I have had a look at articles about it such as: http://bluecrowbar.com/blog/2011/08/coredata-external.html

None of them actually show how to enable it other than telling you to check the box for "allow external storage".

I have an entity set up with some of its attributes as binary data but I can't find the checkbox anywhere. Could someone please explain where I can find it? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure your attribute is set to the type 'Binary Data' and then use the side panel.

Also make sure you are using Xcode 4.2

[image]

Comment: How do you do this for "Transformable" e.g. images?